# cannot call replace of undefined in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table listing values pulled from a database, I then gather up these values and save them into an array to be sent back to the database (with JSON) I'm using

```
        $('#ing_table tr').each(function(row, tr){
            ingredients[row] = {
                "ing" : $(tr).find('input:eq(0)').val(),
                "amt" : $(tr).find('input:eq(1)').val(),
                "meas" : $(tr).find('option:selected').text()
            };
        });
```

to get this info. Generally everything works great except that a few of the strings that occasionally populate the 'ing' row have quotes (") which mess things up.  I tried this:

```
        $('#ing_table tr').each(function(row, tr){
            ingredients[row] = {
                "ing" : $(tr).find('input:eq(0)').val().replace('"', ' '),
                "amt" : $(tr).find('input:eq(1)').val(),
                "meas" : $(tr).find('option:selected').text()
            };
        });
```

but I get a 'cannot call method 'replace' of undefined'

Note: The above code is found in the function stroreIng() which returns ingredients. I used:

```
 var recIng = storeIng();
 recIng = $.toJSON(recIng);
```

this is where it added \\ before the " in the JSON
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try `.replace(/["]/g, ' ')`

Comment: can you give an example of the bad strings?

Comment: If you're getting that message, it means `val()` is retuning `undefined` -- the selector isn't finding anything.

Comment: This is an example of on of the strings:"Beef, chuck, under blade pot roast, boneless, separable lean only, trimmed to 0" fat, all grades, cooked, braised"

Comment: The strings have nothing to do with it. The error means there's no `$(tr).find('input:eq(0)')`.

Comment: And if you're coding the rest of your application correctly, quotes in strings should not cause problems.

Comment: can you do this before `ingredients[row]` in the `$.each` statement and tell us what it says?  `console.log($(row)); console.log($(tr));`  Also - do `amt` and `meas` have values in the array after you do this?

Comment: Yes, all of the rows have values, including 'ing', and everything works until I add .replace()

Comment: I used console log and it returned quite a bit.  What would you like me to find

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there simply isn't any `input` present for some rows. And in case of empty selectors `val()` returns `undefined`:

```
$().val() == undefined //true
```

so your `replace` method fails in such cases. You should use something like this:

```
$('#ing_table tr').each(function(row, tr){
    ingredients[row] = {
        "ing" : ($(tr).find('input:eq(0)').val() || "").replace('"', ' '),
        "amt" : $(tr).find('input:eq(1)').val(),
        "meas" : $(tr).find('option:selected').text()
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the replace() method to work here, but I went to the php  page and was able to use str_replace() to remove the escaped quote.  Now everything works fine.  Thanks for your help!